# Capturing screen with mixed view controllers, 3d scene kit, uiwebkit

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, cgcontext, scenekit

My iPad app can do a screen capture of all view controllers displayed except for a 3d scenekit VC.

Here is my code for capturing the screen

```
  @IBAction func screenImage(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    //Create the UIImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    let screenshot: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //Save it to the camera roll
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, nil, nil, nil)

    //save to user documents access via iTunes
    CaptureOutput.saveImage(screenshot)

  }
```

I set the screen capture VC to the highest atIndex level, all other VC are atIndex less than this.

from the program

[image: capture from program]

taken with my phone.
[image: capture from external phone]

Do I need to force a render of the scene kit?  If so how? Any help?

There is a  confirmed bug (radar number 17851775)

And they also provided a workaround. They suggested that instead of:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, 0);
[self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *im = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
/* Use im */
```

I should do this

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, 0);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *im = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: The other way around, actually. Instead of renderInContext, call drawViewHierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way to capture a view since iOS 7 is to use [`drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)
 (or one of the other methods listed next to it under Capturing a View Snapshot in the docs). That catches things that aren't in the CALayer content, which I believe includes the OpenGL content rendered by SceneKit.

Note that if you only need to capture the SceneKit view and not the rest of the view hierarchy it's in, you can just use the `SCNView` method [`snapshot`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNView_Class/index.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/SCNView/snapshot).

None of these will catch the reflection of your hands and phone, though.

Comment: this worked  `view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)`